# How to output math environment code alongside typeset math?

Tags: math-mode, verbatim, documentation

I have a preamble which defines lots of symbols and a LaTeX document for testing them. In particular, I have source like this:

```
\[\wlength{abc} = 3\]
\[\lang{A} = \lang{\varphi}\]
\[\kplus{L} \defeq \kstar{L} \setminus \emptyword\]
```

Which faithfully creates this:

[image: Default output]

Now I would like to use the same PDF also as a reference which requires the source code to show up. That is, I want something like that:

[image]

Ideally, what I did by hand here (copy source into a `Verbatim` environment from `fancvrb`) would be done automatically; why write the same thing down twice, blowing up everything?

Can this be done and if, how? I guess you would have to rewrite how math environments are translated, but that is beyond me.

*Solutions using `pdflatex` are preferred.*

Comment: Have a look at [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file).

Comment: A recent similar question is also [LaTeX documentation with verbatim environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34720/latex-documentation-with-verbatim-environment/34728#34728), which could be easily adjusted for your case.

Comment: Thanks for those pointers. However, I would like it the other way round: set up a LaTeX file in a way that all math environments are accompanied by their source. That minimises source overhead in this special case and can be used a posteriori without changing each and every environment.

Comment: You could redefine ``\[`` and ``\]`` to do this, but it isn't trivial.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. :>

Comment: Of the packages linked [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file/19299#19299), only `sverb` seems to be fine with maths but has clunky output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For short math you can use the following. It might not give you good results for longer equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\mopen\[
\let\mclose\]

\def\[#1\]{%
    \par\noindent
    \framebox[\linewidth]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}%
    \mopen #1 \mclose
}


\begin{document}
\[a = b^C_D \]
\[A = \varphi\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

For left aligned output you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\[#1\]{%
    \par\medskip\par\noindent
    \framebox[\linewidth][l]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}%
    \par\smallskip
    \(\displaystyle #1 \)
}


\begin{document}
\[a = b^C_D \]
\[A = \varphi\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result2]

---

#### Update:

Here a real verbatim implementation which doesn't add spaces after macros. It goes the other way around. Instead of reading the code normally and then turning it into verbatim, it reads it verbatim and then turns it back to code when required.

I also added line breaking support.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\[{%
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \obeyspaces
    \readmath
}
\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\readmath\expandafter#\expandafter1\string\]{%
    \endgroup
    \par\medskip\par\noindent
    \fbox{\minipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}\raggedright\verbatim@font #1\endminipage}%
    \par\smallskip
    \(\displaystyle \scantokens{#1} \)%
    \par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[a = b^C_D \]

\[A = \varphi\]


\[a = b^C_\text{i} \]


\[ a = 
\alpha_1 + \beta_1 + \gamma_1 +
\alpha_2 + \beta_2 + \gamma_2 +
\alpha_3 + \beta_3 + \gamma_3 +
\alpha_4 + \beta_4 + \gamma_4
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result3]

---

This all requires e-TeX, which is part of any modern LaTeX compiler. I could code an alternative if wanted.

Comment: Great, that's already a good solution! However, verbatim math includes numerous additional spaces after command names. Is this to be expected from `detokenize`? Also, linebreaks inside the box would obviously be great. Is there a chance?

Comment: Yes, `\detokenize` will add a space after every command, to make sure it doesn't fuse together with any trailing text. You would need to use a full verbatim environment to avoid that.

Comment: For the line breaking use the `adjustbox` package and then `\adjustbox{minipage=\linewidth-2\fboxep-2\fboxrule,fbox}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}` instead of `\framebox`. You could also just place a `minipage` environment into `\framebox`.

Comment: @Raphael: See my updated answer now.

Comment: (Legacy comment:) I'm not allowed to use LaTeX syntax in there, right? :> Running `(pdf)latex` on `adjustbox`, I get prompted for `ydocstrip.tex` which I don't have.

Comment: You can use LaTeX macros everywhere here. You don't need `adjustbox`, it is just simpler with it. The latest code above doesn't use it. Anyway, you can get it as ready-to-be-used [TDS ZIP on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox.tds.zip). To extract it you need to install the `ydoc` bundle first.