# In which way have fake spaces made it to actual use?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, pdf

I skimmed the abstracts of [TUG 2014](http://tug.org/tug2014) and stumbled over *"Fake spaces" with pdfTeX -- the best of both worlds* by Ross Moore. The abstract says:

> With the 2014 version of TeX Live, new primitives are included within
>   pdfTeX that allow a `pdffakespace` to be inserted into the PDF
>   content stream, occurring between words and at the end of lines.

In particular, this is intriguing:

> Also to be shown is how a fake space allows extra
>   material, such as the LaTeX source of inline or displayed mathematics,
>   to be included invisibly within the PDF. With a Select/Copy/Paste of
>   the mathematical expression, this included source coding comes along
>   with the pasted text.

Unfortunately, there are no slides available, and the proceedings do not seem to contain anything about this (not that I could access them, as a non-member).

What are current applications of these fake spaces? In particular, has copy-paste of mathematics been implemented so that it may be used without disadvantages?

Comment: The question about copy-paste mathematics is at [Making equations copyable in pdf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119713/250119) .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In reference to your point, *In particular, has copy-paste of mathematics been implemented so that it may be used without disadvantages*

I don't know the particulars of what you cite, but the `accsupp` package allows different things to be displayed in a PDF versus what shows up in a copy paste.

REVISED SOLUTION (using Raphael's suggestion of `\detokenize`)

It would seem that `\detokenize` alleviates the need for separate arguments for the typeset and actual-pdf text, which will greatly streamline the use of this approach.  I extend my thanks to him.

I also show how this even works for `\displaystyle` math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\copypaste[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#1}}}%
      #1%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
What I have is \copypaste{$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$} and \copypaste{$\frac{1}{2}$}.  
Try to copy/paste me.
\copypaste{\[
y = \frac{\cos{x}}{1+\cos{x}}
\]}

Here it is with no copy/paste tuning: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.
\[
y = \frac{\cos{x}}{1+\cos{x}}
\]\end{document}
```

Here is the PDF's appearance:

[image]

Now, when I go into Adobe Reader on the produced PDF file and hit ctl-A ctl-C to copy the whole document, the paste into a text file will appear as:

```
What I have is $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $\frac {1}{2}$ . Try to copy/paste me.
\[ y = \frac {\cos {x}}{1+\cos {x}} \]
Here it is with no copy/paste tuning: x2 + y2 = z2 and 1
2 .
y =
cos x
1 + cos x
1
```

---

ORIGINAL EDITED SOLUTION to allow optional argument with different "ActualText" content, for example, to use `\noexpand` for certain math arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\copypaste[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={#2}}%
      #2%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  \else%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={#1}}%
      #2%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
What I have is \copypaste{$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$} and 
  \copypaste[$\noexpand\frac{1}{2}$]{$\frac{1}{2}$}.  
Try to copy/paste me.

Here it is with no copy/paste tuning: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! I guess a globally activated solution (i.e. copy-paste all math environments as their source) would require `\noexpand` on all macros, otherwise we'd open a can of worms. Ah, fwiwi: works with Evince (3.10.3) as well.

Comment: Where does the spurious space after `\frac` come from, by the way?

Comment: I just remembered [this older answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34779/3213) to a question of mine. Maybe `\detokenize` can be useful here, too, in that we don't have to worry about expansion. Then, the "top-level" LaTeX code ends up being copy-pasted, which may or may not be helpful for people other than the original author. An "expand all macros defined on document level, but not others" may be what you *really* want.

Comment: @Raphael While the space is spurious as compared with what I wrote, I know `\detokenize` introduces the same kind of "spurious" spaces.  Note that they are spurious in the visual sense only.  Functionally, the space is irrelevant.

Comment: @Raphael The `\detokenize` did the trick, alleviating the need for an alternate argument.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, glad I knew something for a change! :) Just one question: would we have to expect any problems should we "enable" this for all math environments by default? (Arguaby, this *should* be what happens when copy-pasting, always.)

Comment: @Raphael I am no expert on either `accsupp` or PDF format in general.  But, just playing around a bit further, I discovered that `accsupp` does not function across paragraph boundaries, so that `\copypaste{a\par b}` fails.  Of course, that is not math, and so this wouldn't usually be a problem unless you were trying to be lazy and apply `\copypaste` across large stretches of code.

Comment: +1: Saw this by reading https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426826: Great idea!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: It's great and how to with UTF characters (like {Q}_{α})?

Comment: @Balaji Try detokenizing what goes into the "ActualText", as in  `\newcommand\copypaste[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#2}}}%
      #2%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  \else%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#1}}}%
      #2%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  \fi%
}` and compile in lualatex or xelatex.  Not sure if this will work for your use case, though.