# How make formulas in the PDF not selectable?

Tags: packages, code

Mathematical formulas in a PDF from LaTex generate lots of noise while reading it with Text-to-speech software. This is why I would like find a way to make all the set of symbols inside the formulas not selectable.

There is already a package that allows to do that? (It has to work only for formulas if not all the document become inaccessible by text-to-speech)

If not, which is the best way to solve this kind of problem? Writing a new macro or modify how the compiler generate the PDF from Tex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have a hunch that the package [`accsupp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) will be helpful here. You can give answerers a head-start by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that sets up a document that might be used for testing solutions.

Comment: Hi @PaulGessler, thanks for the advices. I had a look to the documentation of the package accsupp but I don't see how/where it can be useful for what I need. Could you give me more information about how to use that?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use  It shows how to get a copy/paste of PDF formulas to provide the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 9):

The [`accsupp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) package can indeed be of some help here.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}

\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=I don't want you to select this text.}
$\sum_{x > 1} x$
\EndAccSupp{}

\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=The sum of all the x greater than 1.}
$\sum_{x > 1} x$
\EndAccSupp{}

\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=Some math}
$\sum_{x > 1} x$
\EndAccSupp{}

\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=}
$\sum_{x > 1} x$
\EndAccSupp{}

\end{document}
```

Then, when selected, the math equation will actually read a text of your choice ("*I don't want you to select this text.*"), a description of the equation ("*The sum of all the x greater than 1.*"), a simple message ("*Some math*") or … nothing.

I haven't tried with a text-to-speech software, but I think this should work just as fine.

Comment: How can we combine the [copy-paste](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233397/3213) fix with giving useful text to a screen reader? The two solutions use the same mechanism so they seem to conflict.

Comment: I don't think you can combine those two techniques: what is going to be selectable is precisely what is going to be read, you can't offer two different things at the same time. So, you have to make a choice, I'm afraid…

Comment: Too bad. There could conceivably be more than one "alt text" property in PDF; both copy-paste and screen reading are utterly basic functions, and would usually not have the same content.

Comment: Honestly: ask the question. You are right, there might be more than one way of adding "alt text" to a pdf, but I don't know if it is the case, nor if it exists. It is an interesting question, though, that could be of practical use.

Comment: [Done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352649/can-we-get-maths-in-pdfs-that-can-be-copy-pasted-and-screen-read).