# Customize copy-text for box

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, wolfram-mathematica

## Motivation

My end goal is to include more Mathematica expressions in LaTeX-pdfs that are copy-paste-able back into Mathematica notebooks.  For instance, the code

```
\usepackage{mmacells}
...
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  \mmaSub{\(\pmb{\partial}\)}{x}\mmaSup{x}{2}
\end{mmaCell}
```

yields

[image: in1 pdxx^2]

but if you copy that and paste it into a Mathematica notebook, it makes

[image: invalid mma code]

instead of the 'correct'

[image: valid mma code]

This makes sense: the raw copied text is "∂ x x2".  Other unicode characters generated by CellToTeX copy like "\[Pi]", one of Mathematica's auto expanding inputs (if you paste *that* string into a notebook, it'll show as π).  There is some raw text that produces the correct Mathematica code, though:

```
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)
```

Basically, \!\(...\) with the ! says to auto expand, and wrapping things in \(\) and with \* does other parsing stuff.  So if *that* string was to be copied when selecting the stuff in the pdf, it would be pasted beautifully back into a notebook.

## Question

Is there a good way or package to specify what is copied for some selected pdf content of some cells?  Can I wrap the `\begin{mmaCell}...\end{mmaCell}` with something like a `href{\\!\\(\\*SuperscriptBox...\\)}{...}`, but instead of a link, change the copy-paste content?  Or do I have to begin spelunking inside the TeXbook, but probably not that -- I might have to spelunk in pdflatex or something else.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but the mmacells package is pretty much just styling, and can't help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which way have fake spaces made it to actual use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use)

Comment: The question may not seem related at first but the final part and the answer seem particularly relevant.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545273/copyable-math-formulas is a bit more clear/extensive.