# Write environment body verbatim to a file

Tags: verbatim, write-file

How can one write the body of an environment verbatim to an external file. I tried the following but get problems if the body contains undefined macros (error) or e.g. a `%` (disappears in the output).

**Try 1**
Using `environ` to get the environment content.

```
\ProvidesPackage{tofile1}

\RequirePackage{environ}

% counter for external files
\newcounter{TF@File}

\newwrite\TF@out

\NewEnviron{tofile}{%
    \stepcounter{TF@File}
    \edef\TF@outFile{ext-\jobname-\theTF@File.tex}
    \typeout{Name: \TF@outFile}
    \immediate\openout\TF@out=\TF@outFile
    \typeout{\TF@outFile\space opened}
    \immediate\write\TF@out{\BODY}
    \typeout{\TF@outFile\space written}
    \immediate\closeout\TF@out
    \typeout{\TF@outFile\space closed}
}
```

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tofile1}

\begin{document}
Test

\begin{tofile}
That's {a short Test}
which works
but ignores line breaks
\end{tofile}

Text

\begin{tofile}
\xx That's {another Test}%
This one doesn't work ...
it gives an error because \xx is undefined
\end{tofile}
\end{document}
```

This one creates the two desired files `ext-test-1.tex` and `ext-test-1.tex` but linebreaks are ignored and an undefined control sequence (`\xx`) causes an error. Furthermore the percent char is interpreted as comment not as simple character. I guess come catcode magic could help.

**Try 2**
Using the `filecontents` package.

```
\ProvidesPackage{tofile2}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

% counter for external files
\newcounter{TF@File}

\newwrite\TF@out

\newenvironment{tofile}{%
    \stepcounter{TF@File}
    \edef\TF@outFile{ext-\jobname-\theTF@File.tex}
    \begin{filecontents}{\TF@outFile}
}{
    \end{filecontents}
}
```

```
Same test file as above ...
```

This one creates only the first file `ext-test-1.tex` and the an error occurs because the end of `filecontens` can’t be determined correctly.

Is there another way do do this, maybe a package?

Comment: The reason why the `filecontents` solutions doesn't work is that it looks for `\end{filecontents}` verbatim and can't find it inside `\end{tofile}`. In general you can't include verbatim macros or environments in other macros or environments.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Yea, I thought so …

Comment: have a look at the `answers` package too

Comment: About writing `%` into a file see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34390/6865

Comment: Depends on the use case, `scontents` or `filecontentsdef` to store the content in memory instead of an external file may be better. //// The `filecontents` environment is actually extensible, but you need `\filecontents` ... `\endfilecontents` -- [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130296/250119). Also the starred version does not include the header -- see section 8.11 (page 62) of latex2e.pdf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can look at the definition of `verbatimwrite` in `verbatim.sty` or use the facilities provided by the **fancyvrb** package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{tobiwrite}[1]
  {\typeout{Writing file #1}\VerbatimOut{#1}}
  {\endVerbatimOut}

\begin{document}
\begin{tobiwrite}{tobi.txt}
a

b
c
\end{tobiwrite}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\typeout` you can do whatever you want (for example, checking whether the file already exists with `\IfFileExists`).

Comment: @MartinScharrer, egreg: Thank you both seems like both answers math my questions. Could you pleas figure out the differences if there are any?

Comment: @Tobi A very late answer, but it seems I missed seeing your comment. What are the differences? Well, `listings` loads `fancyvrb`, first of all. However, the definition of `\lst@BeginWriteFile` is different from `\VerbatimOut`, since many more settings are necessary for supporting the full power of `listings`. If you're only interested in verbatim copy, `\VerbatimOut` is more efficient.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to use internal macros from the `listings` package to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

\lstnewenvironment{yourenv}{%
  % some code before
  % including \lstset{..}
  % Write file to given filename
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\jobname.txt}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile% closes output file
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% ...    
\end{document}
```

Compare with the similar code I provided in my answers to the following questions:
[LaTeX documentation with verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34720/latex-documentation-with-verbatim-environment/34728#34728)
[How to use a \write command inside a \newenvironment ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20957/how-to-use-a-write-command-inside-a-newenvironment/20989#20989)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to remove an indention (white space at the beginning of the line) while writing the file?

Comment: @Tobi: Have a look at `listings` `gobble` option. Not sure if it works with writting files.

Comment: Hm … Seems like the `gobble` function is hard wired with the user level macros and can’t be used with `\lst@BeginWriteFile` …