# Writing environment content verbatim to file, calling Graphviz and including source/image

Tags: listings, shell-escape, write-file

Based on [Write environment body verbatim to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/write-environment-body-verbatim-to-a-file) I try to write the content of a environment verbatim to a file, call an external tool (in my case the awesome [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)) and include the source code plus the generated graphics.

The following actually works, but displays a empty `listings` at the top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\lstnewenvironment{colenv}[1]{%
\lst@BeginWriteFile{#1.dot}%
}{%
 \lst@EndWriteFile% closes output file
  \immediate\write18{dot -Tpdf -o #1.pdf #1.dot}
  \lstinputlisting{#1.dot}
\includegraphics{#1.pdf}
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\lstset{%
    frame=single, %
    numbers=left, %
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb}, %
}

\begin{document}

\begin{colenv}{abc}{0.5}{0.5}
digraph G {
 node [shape=box,style=filled,
  color=".6 .3 1.0"];
 edge[arrowhead="none"];
 a [label = "12344445"];
 b [label = "67890"];
 a -> b;
}
\end{colenv}

\end{document}
```

[image: worksbasically]

Using the first solution in the above mentioned question does not work either since the value of `#1` lost in the environment definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{colenv}[1]
  {\typeout{Writing file #1}\VerbatimOut{#1.dot}}
  {\endVerbatimOut %
% Here it does not work
 \immediate\write18{dot -Tpdf -o #1.pdf #1.dot}%
 \lstinputlisting{#1.dot}%
 \includegraphics{#1.pdf}%
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}

\lstset{%
    frame=single, %
    numbers=left, %
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb}, %
}

\begin{document}

Test!

\begin{colenv}{abc}
digraph G {
 node [shape=box,style=filled,
  color=".6 .3 1.0"];
 edge[arrowhead="none"];
 a [label = "12344445"];
 b [label = "67890"];
 a -> b;
}
\end{colenv}

% Here it works...
%\immediate\write18{dot -Tpdf -o abc.pdf abc.dot}%
%\lstinputlisting{abc.dot}%
%\includegraphics{abc.pdf}%

\end{document}
```

results in

```
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz))
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \endcolenv.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.17 }

?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The name of the file and a command to run are saved globally with
`\xdef\d@tn@me` and `\xdef\r@ncmd`, and two token registers + `\edef\d@r@ncmd` are used
to reduce the number of `\expandafter` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{colenv}[1]%
  {\xdef\d@tn@me{#1}%
  \xdef\r@ncmd{dot -Tpdf -o #1.pdf #1.dot}%
  \typeout{Writing file #1}\VerbatimOut{#1.dot}% 
  }
  {\endVerbatimOut %
 \toks0{\immediate\write18}%
 \expandafter\toks\expandafter1\expandafter{\r@ncmd}%
 \edef\d@r@ncmd{\the\toks0{\the\toks1}}\d@r@ncmd %
 \lstinputlisting{\d@tn@me.dot}%
 \includegraphics{\d@tn@me.pdf}%
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}

\lstset{%
    frame=single, %
    numbers=left, %
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb}, %
}

\begin{document}
Test!
\begin{colenv}{abc}
digraph G {
 node [shape=box,style=filled,
  color=".6 .3 1.0"];
 edge[arrowhead="none"];
 a [label = "12344445"];
 b [label = "67890"];
 a -> b;
}
\end{colenv}
\end{document}
```