# Append verbatim material to a file

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb, write

I am using the `fancyvrb` package. I'd like to create a verbatim-like environment that does the following two things:

1) Append the verbatim material as-is to a file that has already been opened.
2) Output the verbatim material like `UseVerbatim` would do.

I have tried to re-use the `SaveVerbatim` environment and to output the material with `\immediate\write\FILE{\UseVerbatim{VERB}}` but this doesn't as `\UseVerbatim` needs more than expansion. Adding `\protect` in front of `\UseVerbatim` didn't help either.

A *non-working* example follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newwrite\FILE
\immediate\openout\FILE=\jobname.out

\newenvironment{chunk}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment{chunk}\begin{SaveVerbatim}[gobble=2,commentchar=\%,commandchars=\\\{\}]{VERB}%
}{%
  \end{SaveVerbatim}%
  \UseVerbatim{VERB}%
  \immediate\write\FILE{\UseVerbatim{VERB}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{chunk}
  First line.
  \texttt{Second} line.
\end{chunk}

\end{document}
```

Comment: afaik, this isn't possible; it would require a rewrite of tex engine's file handling, and would also require some new macro-level facility to access the new stuff; an alternative would be to write a shell script (or .bat file on widnoze), to be executed after the latex run.

Comment: What exactly, do you think, is not possible? I have the feeling I could get what I want but reimplementing much of `fancyvrb` but I don't think it is a good idea to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MarcNieper-Wißkirchen: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added a MNWE :-)

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/write-environment-body-verbatim-to-a-file

Comment: Since you also want to format the contents of the “verbatim” environment, the easiest method is using a modified version of `SaveVerbatim` that writes in the `\FILE` stream *and* in a temporary file that's then input and formatted as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this for literate programming?  If so, then maybe you want a specialized literate programming tool?

Yes, you could obviously do this by reimplementing `fancyvrb.sty`.  Just tweak the lines containing [`\openout`](https://github.com/flame/libflame/blob/master/docs/libflame/fancyvrb.sty#L1236) and [`\closeout`](https://github.com/flame/libflame/blob/master/docs/libflame/fancyvrb.sty#L1242), or even add the ability to write to an arbitrary handle as opposed to `\FV@OutFile`.  Ain't the easiest or most robust solution though.

Instead, I've a Perl script called `cat_latex_env` that uses the Perl flip-flop operator `..` to do exactly this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub usage { die "Usage: cat_latex_env enviroment_name [filename]\n"; }
usage if ($#ARGV < 0);

my $env = shift;
my $begin = quotemeta "\\begin{$env}";
my $end = quotemeta "\\end{$env}";
while (<>) {
        if (/$begin/../$end/) {
                next if /$begin/ || /$end/;
                print;
        }
}
```

Just run `cat_latex_env chunk file1.tex > file2.tex` in your `Makefile`.