# Can a GLE code be empaded in Latex document?

Tags: pdf, external-files

I am searching for a good tool for graphs and charts and found [Graphics Layout Engine](http://www.gle-graphics.org/). Am I able to include a code written in GLE within a latex document?
The aim is not including it as a file in the document but as a script within the latex script, is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Of course you are if you're willing to write an interpreter in TeX that reads that format (I never heard of one as of now). Note however that there are packages like `pgfplots` and `TikZ` around, which also enable you to produce high quality plots and images.

Comment: that page says that it will generate pdf, which you can then include into latex

Comment: It really depends on what tool you can use and how far you want to go. If you use MATLAB, you can create your figures and print them as eps or other vector or raster graphics formats. If you use python, you can do the same with the `matplotlib` library. If you want to go deep in the code to fully control the output, you may use `pgfplots` of `TikZ` as proposed by @Skillmon ...

Comment: In addition to @BambOo: Python's `matplotlib` can export to `pgf`-code which can be included directly into your LaTeX document with the `pgf` (or `TikZ`) package. This way every font aspect should match the rest of your document (but it might really slow down your compilation process).

Comment: Judging by the comments and the suggested duplicate, some clarification might be in order. Do you want to place *the code itself* in the PDF, or do you want to write GLE code in the `.tex` file, and get a diagram in the PDF? (I understood you to mean the latter.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right, yes I meant the latter.

Comment: Right, so the suggested duplicate doesn't fit. (I've voted to reopen.) I don't know whether such a thing exists, in the meantime you can of course use David's suggestion.

Comment: Please clarify the question by editing it.

Comment: It is not a stackexchange post, but other people have the same questions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/2vou3o/best_programpackage_for_creating_lots_of_function/). The thing is that you have so much possibilities that it is really depending on your actual experience. If you are already "fluent" in GLE coding, please use it. If not, using the already existing packages for latex would be a better idea. What experience do you currently have with such programs @User505 ?

Comment: @BambOo Thank you for your comment, actually I am middle level in using latex but not aware that much on GLE or the package (pgfplots) that Latex offers since I'm trying to create a chart and I read [the documentation](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) but seriously it wasn't easy to understand for me, I found the  [this example](http://www.gle-graphics.org/examples/2dsimple/fruitbar.pdf)  in GLE and it is easy to edit that is why I want to see if there is such a way enables me to adapt the GLE code in the Latex code.

Comment: @User505, I personally started to use `pgfplots` and `tikz` a year ago, both are very flexible and you can get a lot of help between the community of users and the documentation, which I think should guide your choice, in any case, good luck !

Comment: Unrelated: the `pgfplots` manual you linked to is quite old (version 1.3, from 2010), you can find the manual for the current version (1.15, from 2017) at for example CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots Not saying the new one is easier to understand, but it does also have a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the GLE code in your document, write it to a temporary file, call GLE on this file, and include the output as an image. Writing the contents of an environment to a file can be done with `\VerbatimOut` from the `fancyvrb` package, see [Write environment body verbatim to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/write-environment-body-verbatim-to-a-file). Calling an external program can be done with `\immediate\write18` (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex), which requires the `--shell-escape` flag when compiling the document.

A counter called `glenum` is used to prevent caching by creating different filenames in case you want to compile more than one figure.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcounter{glenum}
\setcounter{glenum}{0}
\newenvironment{GLEinclude}[1]
  {\xdef\mywd{#1}\VerbatimOut{\jobname.\theglenum.gle}}
  {\endVerbatimOut%
  \immediate\write18{gle -output \jobname.\theglenum.gle.pdf \jobname.\theglenum.gle}%
  \includegraphics[width=\mywd]{{\jobname.\theglenum.gle}.pdf}%
  \stepcounter{glenum}%
  }

\begin{document}
Here is a tree fractal compiled with GLE:

\begin{GLEinclude}{5cm}
size 32 22

a = 3; b = 4; c = sqrt(a^2+b^2)

sub pythagorean n
   local red   = (34+n*92)/(n+1)
   local green = (139+n*64)/(n+1)
   local blue  = (34+n*51)/(n+1)
   box c c fill rgb255(red,green,blue)
   if n = 0 then return
   begin translate c c
      begin rotate todeg(-acos(a/c))
         begin scale a/c a/c
            begin translate -c 0
               pythagorean n-1
            end translate
         end scale
      end rotate
   end translate
   begin translate 0 c
      begin rotate todeg(acos(b/c))
         begin scale b/c b/c
            pythagorean n-1
         end scale
      end rotate
   end translate
end sub

begin translate 16 0
   pythagorean 10
end translate
\end{GLEinclude}

Also known as a \textbf{Pythagorean tree}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]